# Things to do everyday to get better at UX (Design Thinking)

Tags: design

I was at a meet up and I was blown away by how quickly the Designer was able to think on the spot. His advice was to practice design thinking every day. He recommended conceptualizing a problem everyday and try to solve it. So what are the exercises UX designers should do everyday to improve their Design Thinking?

Comment: This reminds me of the old joke “How do you get to Carnegie Hall?” --- “Practice, practice, practice.”

Answer (score 4):

## Work on hard projects

Whenever my "day job" has become less challenging, I've found side projects that offer bigger problems. There's always someone willing to pay you to figure things out.

There's no better way to learn than solving real-world problems with real-world money on the line.

## Learning the ropes

If you're not yet to a place in your career where people are willing to pay you for this, you have to get creative. Find people who have a good product or service idea and offer to work for little to nothing just for the experience.

You might even be able to negotiate a slice of equity in the new venture. I still take on a project like this every now and then because I see potential and the problem seems challenging.

If you love what you do and you aren't afraid to network and stretch your skills, it's easy to gain experience.

Comment: The "hard projects" bit is exceptionally relevant. 

I find it's always worth having a list of hard problems in the back of my mind (or in a notebook) and just revisit the list occasionally.  

They're rarely solved by just sitting down and grinding on them, but are frequently solved while working on _something else entirely_.  Likewise, when I take a break from the day-to-day to think about the hard problems, I frequently come back to the day-to-day with a pile of new ideas.

Ideas often come when you're looking elsewhere.

Comment: @AdrianLong makes a great point. It's been my experience that taking on "side" projects that present difficult challenges always benefit the other projects on my desk.

Answer (score 1):

That's a very good suggestion your mate gave you and of course, to become better at anything, you have to practice and make yourself better than the self a day before.

Some of the methods that I practice are :

1. **Books** -  Read as many good books as possible, try to get into the shoes of the authors who came up with the problems and the solutions. This will treat you with loads of examples and will surely provide a good experience+exposure to look at the problems and designing a solution.
2. **Read** - Apart from the books, there are so many experts who are on medium or with own blogs, who write about their experience.
3. **Practical usability methods** - There is this [website](http://practicaluxmethods.com/) which provide you a glipse of the practical approach of almost every possible UX method.
4. **Level up your problems** - Start designing solution for the easy problems today and level them up by increasing the user base, the business requirements, the user requirements(if you are working on your own projects).
5. **Motivation** - Try to follow the royalty achievers of this domain and try to follow their portfolios, work like [this portfolio](http://simonpan.com/) and apply the similar problem-solving behavior(not the same approach) in your problems.

And Last

6. **Rigidity** - Be rigid with your terms of working and start+enjoy the day with full enthusiasm so that your way of working can be irritating, frustrating but also fun too.

Comment: Another useful addition to #4 and #6 - applying extra constraints to your work as a thought exercise can be helpful.

"What if I wanted this whole complex process to be achieved in a single click?  What would that look like?  What's the closest I can get to that?  What's in the way of getting closer?"

"The user doesn't want to do this, but they have to.  What would it look like we did it for them instead?  What's in the way of doing that?"

It's not always going to bring revelations, but it stops you settling on just meeting a stated goal and helps you come up with game changers.